# How do I get a macro to run the same operation but with 2 seperate workbooks, not the same ones I used to record the macro?

Tags: vba

I hope this is a clearer description of what I want to achieve.

I just did a copy and paste values only and it did the operation for me. I was hoping a macro might speed the process up a bit.

Essentially I want to copy cells 2,4,6,8,10....48 from column D in a particular workbook and paste the values into cells 23,24,25....46 in column J in a second workbook. The next step is to copy cells 3,5,7,9.....49 from column D in the first workbook and paste the values only into cells 23,24,25....46 in column X in the second workbook.

Obviously I could copy and paste these but I have thousands of these to do and was hoping a macro could help.

Comment: What code have you so far?

Comment: I tried to create a macro by recording it in excel, but it did not work very well. I cannot post it here because it is too long.

Answer (score 0):

That might help:

```
Sub CopyColumn()
Dim i As Long, k As Long, wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim columnD As Long, columnJ As Long, columnX As Long
Set wb1 = Workbooks("workbook1.xls") ' replace it with the actual name
Set wb2 = Workbooks("workbook2.xls") ' replace with the actual name
columnD = Range("D1").Column
columnJ = Range("J1").Column
columnX = Range("X1").Column
k = 23
For i = 2 To 49 Step 2
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, columnJ) = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, columnD)
    wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(k, columnX) = wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i + 1, columnD)
    k = k + 1
Next i
End Sub
```

This does, what you have asked for. But you have to replace the names of the workbooks and eventually the names of the sheets.
I've tested it with some random data and it worked.

Comment: Subscript out of range is what it says

Comment: Click on debug. Then you can see which line causes the error.

Comment: If I am open in either Book1 or Book2 and try to run the Macro the error occurs

Comment: Set wb1 = Workbooks("Book1.xls")

Comment: Are both workbooks opened in excel when you run the macro? Is "Book1.xls" the real filename of the workbook or is it "Book1.xlsm" or something like this?

Comment: They are both open, but yes the files are probably called Book1.xlsx etc. Also I realised I had not saved them as yet, do you think this makes a difference?? I did change the file name and saved them and now it works. I will run this across a couple of files and get back to you.

Comment: I just tried it with 2 new workbooks and I am getting the same run time error at the same line. Any ideas?

Comment: Also the macro was not available to be used in the new workbooks so I tried running it from the PERSONAL.XLSB workbook

Comment: You have to make sure, that the filenames are correct, the sheet names are correct and that the workbooks are open. If that's ok (beware of typos...) everything will work as expected. (if everything works, please accept my answer)

Comment: Thanks mate, the macro works perfectly. I am careful with saving and naming and all is good.